# Node js, REST, Google API, Realtime Tracking, Pusher

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api

Я недавно взялась за изучение JS и Node и возникли некоторые вопросы.

Есть такое учебное задание для веб-приложения, спроектированного по REST:

Алекс является оператором небольшой пиццерии в городе. Чтобы расширить свою клиентуру, он решил в прошлом году предложить услугу доставки,но ему трудно правильно координировать поставки. Несколько водителей перевозят заказы по разным адресам в этом районе и поскольку Алекс не знает, как выглядит текущее состояние заказов и где находится курьер, ему и его сотрудникам сложно оптимально планировать поездки. Часто новые заказы добавляются, когда все курьеры находятся в пути. Пока что Алекс пытается выяснить по телефону, какой из курьеров должен логически принять новую доставку из пиццерии.

Таким образом, веб-приложение должно 
1. Отслеживать трекинг курьеров в реальном времени через Google Maps API
2. Отслеживать состояние заказов, то есть, если пришел заказ, а все машины в пути, то из управления можно посмотреть, какая машина ближе и сколько у нее активных заказов и передать ей инструкцию, чтобы она заезжала за новым заказом (управление ивентами через Pusher)
3. Заказы можно удалить, обновить.

Засим у меня вопрос: Как правильно прикрутить этот google Maps API и использовать Pusher, так, чтобы это все работало совместно с модулями orders и suppliers, притом данные хранились в MongoDB?

Туториал по прикрутке Google API и Pusher для трекинга взят отсюда:

https://blog.pusher.com/track-pizza-realtime-pusher-google-maps/ Git Репозиторий: https://github.com/ankeetmaini/food-express

Есть понимание общей концепции, но у меня нет пока опыта в имплементации. Или надо "разбить" все тоже на модули? Но как?

К тому же, есть вопросы, правильно ли реализована коммуникация с модулями в app.js.

app.js начальный "чистый" вариант:

```html
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
 
// PizzaNodes app Server Setup
const app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app)
 
// Bodyparser
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
 
// Routes
const supplierRoutes = require('./routes/suppliers')
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/orders')
 
// Server Setup / Connections
server.listen(3000, () => {
})
 
// Konfigurationen fГјr 'Accessability' => Clients auГџerhalb des Servers kГ¶nnen auf diese REST API zugreifen
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PATCH, POST, GET, DELETE')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})
 
// Middleware supplierRoutes
app.use('/suppliers', supplierRoutes)
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes)
```

router/orders.js

```html
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const router = express.Router()
 
// MongoDB & Mongoose
const Supplier = require('../schemas/supplierSchema')
const Order = require('../schemas/orderSchema')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const assert = require('assert')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const dbname = 'pizzanodes'
const client = new MongoClient(url);
 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
 
//Mongoose methods
 
router.get('/:_id', (req, res, next) => {
    Order.findOne({_id: req.params._id}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Order.find({}).select('_id customer products link').exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) res.send(err.message)
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
router.patch('/:_id', (req, res, next) => {
    Order.update({_id: req.params._id}, {
        $set: {
            customer: req.body.customer,
            products: req.body.products
        }
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) res.send(err.message)
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
 
    let _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
    const order = new Order({
        _id: _id,
        customer: req.body.customer,
        products: req.body.products,
        orderlink: "http://localhost:3000/orders/" + _id
    })
    order.save()
    res.send("Order " + req.body.customer + " created")
})
 
router.delete('/:_id', ((req, res, next) => {
    Order.deleteOne({_id: req.params._id}, (err) => {
        if (err) res.send(err.message)
        res.send("Order " + req.params._id + " deleted")
    })
}))
 
module.exports = router
```

router/supplier.js

```html
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const router = express.Router()
 
// MongoDB & Mongoose
const Supplier = require('../schemas/supplierSchema')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const assert = require('assert')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
const dbname = 'pizzanodes'
const client = new MongoClient(url);
 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')
 
//Mongoose Methoden
 
router.get('/:_id', (req, res, next) => {
    Supplier.findOne({_id: req.params._id}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Supplier.find({}).select('_id name orders').exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) res.send(err.message)
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
router.patch('/:_id', (req, res, next) => {
    Supplier.update({_id: req.params._id}, {$set: {orders: req.body.orders}}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) res.send(err.message)
        res.send(result)
    })
})
 
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const supplier = new Supplier({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        orders: req.body.orders
    })
    supplier.save()
    res.send("Supplier " + req.body.name + " created")
})
 
router.delete('/:_id', ((req, res, next) => {
    Supplier.deleteOne({_id: req.params._id}, (err) => {
        if (err) res.send(err.message)
        res.send("Supplier " + req.params._id + " deleted")
    })
}))
 
router.delete
module.exports = router
```

schema/orderSchema.js

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    customer: {type: String, required: true},
    products: {type: [String], required: true},
    orderlink: {type: String, required: true}
})
 
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
module.exports = Order
```

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 
const supplierSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    orders: {type: [String]}
})
 
const Supplier = mongoose.model('Supplier', supplierSchema)
module.exports = Supplier
```

app.js с добавлением pusher и карт

```html
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const Pusher = require('pusher');
 
// PizzaNodes app Server Setup
const app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app)
 
// Bodyparser
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
 
// Routes
const supplierRoutes = require('./routes/suppliers')
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/orders')
const openweather = require('./routes/openweatherApi')
 
// Server Setup / Connections
server.listen(3000, () => {
})
 
// Konfigurationen fГјr 'Accessability' => Clients auГџerhalb des Servers kГ¶nnen auf diese REST API zugreifen
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Acess-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PATCH, POST, GET, DELETE')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})
 
// Middleware supplierRoutes
app.use('/suppliers', supplierRoutes)
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes)
 
 
(function () {
    var username;
 
    // reference for DOM nodes
    var saveNameButton = document.getElementById('saveNameButton');
    var saveNameBox = document.getElementById('name-box');
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
    var welcomeHeading = document.getElementById('welcome-message');
    var deliveryHeroBox = document.getElementById('delivery-hero-box');
    var deliveryHeroesAddButton = document.getElementById('addDeliveryHeroButton');
    var deliveryHeroNameInput = document.getElementById('deliveryHeroName');
    var deliveryHeroesList = document.getElementById('delivery-heroes-list');
 
    // handy variables
    var locationWatcher;
    var myLastKnownLocation;
    var sendLocationInterval;
    var deliveryHeroesLocationMap = {};
    var deliveryHeroesMarkerMap = {};
 
    // mode - user's or delivery guy's
    var mode = getUrlParameter('mode') || 'user';
 
    // load the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 14
    });
 
    // get the location via Geolocation API
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
        var currentLocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            // save my last location
            var location = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
 
            myLastKnownLocation = location;
            map.setCenter(location);
        });
    }
 
    // initialize pusher
    var pusher = new Pusher('sjdhuh43372344656', {
        cluster: 'eu',
        encrypted: true
    });
 
    // add eventlisteners
    saveNameButton.addEventListener('click', saveName);
    deliveryHeroesAddButton.addEventListener('click', addDeliveryHero);
 
    // all functions, event handlers
    function saveName (e) {
        var input = nameInput.value;
        if (input && input.trim()) {
            username = input;
 
            // hide the name box
            saveNameBox.classList.add('hidden');
 
            // set the name
            welcomeHeading.innerHTML = 'Hi! <strong>' + username +
                (mode === 'user'
                    ? '</strong>, type in your Delivery Hero\'s name to track your food.'
                    : '</strong>, type in the customer name to locate the address');
            // show the delivery hero's div now
            deliveryHeroBox.classList.remove('hidden');
 
            // create a private channel with the username
            createMyLocationChannel(username);
        }
        return;
    }
 
    function addDeliveryHero (e) {
        var deliveryHeroName = deliveryHeroNameInput.value;
        // if already present return
        if (deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName]) return;
        if (deliveryHeroName) {
            var deliveryHeroChannelName = 'private-' + deliveryHeroName;
            var deliveryHeroChannel = pusher.subscribe(deliveryHeroChannelName);
            deliveryHeroChannel.bind('client-location', function (nextLocation) {
                // first save the location
                // bail if location is same
                var prevLocation = deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName] || {};
                deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName] = nextLocation;
                showDeliveryHeroOnMap(deliveryHeroName, false, true, prevLocation);
            });
        }
 
        // add the name to the list
        var deliveryHeroTrackButton = document.createElement('button');
        deliveryHeroTrackButton.classList.add('small');
        deliveryHeroTrackButton.innerHTML = deliveryHeroName;
        deliveryHeroTrackButton.addEventListener('click', showDeliveryHeroOnMap.bind(null, deliveryHeroName, true, false, {}));
        deliveryHeroesList.appendChild(deliveryHeroTrackButton);
    }
 
    function showDeliveryHeroOnMap (deliveryHeroName, center, addMarker, prevLocation) {
        if (!deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName]) return;
        // first center the map
        if (center) map.setCenter(deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName]);
        var nextLocation = deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName];
 
        // add a marker
        if ((prevLocation.lat === nextLocation.lat) && (prevLocation.lng === nextLocation.lng)) {
            return;
        }
 
        if (addMarker) {
            var marker = deliveryHeroesMarkerMap[deliveryHeroName];
            marker = marker || new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                label: deliveryHeroName,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            });
            marker.setPosition(deliveryHeroesLocationMap[deliveryHeroName]);
            deliveryHeroesMarkerMap[deliveryHeroName] = marker;
        }
    }
 
    function triggerLocationChangeEvents (channel, location) {
        // update myLastLocation
        myLastKnownLocation = location;
        channel.trigger('client-location', location);
    }
 
    function createMyLocationChannel (name) {
        var myLocationChannel = pusher.subscribe('private-' + name);
        myLocationChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
            // safe to now trigger events
            // use the watchPosition API to watch the changing location
            // and trigger events with new coordinates
            locationWatcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
                var location = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                triggerLocationChangeEvents(myLocationChannel, location);
            });
 
            // also start a setInterval to keep sending the loction every 5 secs
            sendLocationInterval = setInterval(function () {
                // not using `triggerLocationChangeEvents` to keep the pipes different
                myLocationChannel.trigger('client-location', myLastKnownLocation)
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
 
    // function to get a query param's value
    function getUrlParameter(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
        var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
        var results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
}());
```

server.js

```html
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Pusher = require('pusher');
 
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 
// to serve our JavaScript, CSS and index.html
app.use(express.static('./'));
 
var pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: '6982244445',
    key: 'abdf4534545b1a0897b58e79214',
    secret:  '3247623462332423423',
    cluster: 'eu'
});
 
 
app.post('/pusher/auth', function(req, res) {
    var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
    var channel = req.body.channel_name;
    var auth = pusher.authenticate(socketId, channel);
    res.send(auth);
});
 
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000'));
```